# how to find a list of interfaces in win32com python

Tags: python, win32com

Is there a way to generate a list of all the interfaces implemented by a COM object? I'm new to COM objects so my vocabulary may not be correct. I've added comments in the code below for what I'm looking for. This code is a snippet from the Gepard repo at gitlab.ipfdd.de/GEPARD/gepard/-/wikis/home.

````py
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

CLSID = "{C45E77CE-3D66-489A-B5E2-159F443BD1AA}"
    hostname = gethostname()
    self.IBUCSAccess = win32com.client.DispatchEx(CLSID, machine=hostname, 
                                                      clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER)

IBUCSCore = win32com.client.CastTo(self.IBUCSAccess, 'IBUCSCore') #first question, how would I know this COM object has an "IBUCSCore" interface?

IBUCSCore.GetSubSystemDefaultInterface("UserParameters|SamplePositioning|AbsolutePositionX") #Second question, where would I find these interface names, the win32com documentation isn't very helpful if you aren't already well versed in COM objects```
````

Comment: Do a search on your system for `oleview.exe`. This is the Object/Interface viewer supplied with the Windows SDK. You might find it under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64` or similar. The first time you run it, you need to be elevated to Admin rights (as the application needs to register a DLL).

Comment: I've browsed the COM interface using OleViewNet. the specific CLSID doesn't show up as registered, but using OleViewNet I can create an instance from that CLSID. I can then access the IBUCSCore interface which is where my predecessor can search for all of these default interfaces. But the call on GetSubSystemsList doesn't bring up anything

https://imgur.com/a/4MGHZZ3